# What are the career prospects after being an RA?

Tags: graduate-school, job, computer-science, research-assistantship

I'll be eligible to apply for the master's in Computer Science within a semester (2 max). I'm working as an undergrad for a research group (I'm implementation -- programming).  I'd like to know what I could reasonably expect (in terms of job prospects and recruitment if any) if I work as an RA.  How are RA's typically viewed by prospective employers?

Initially, I thought this would be good and that RA's are sought after since they're pretty well educated and have been working in cutting edge areas.  But then, I wasn't sure if it's just too far removed from industry and that employers might think you just didn't bother to pursue any work in the private sector while getting a degree in a field that is highly employable by the private sector (i.e. they might not be sympathetic to your desire to do interesting research work as opposed to straight coding production work as is often in industry).

Comment: It worked well for me. 4 (good) job offers after finishing undergrad. I put it 75% down to my RA work, based on where the discussions were centered in all my interviews (as well as the rest of my resume being bland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an RA (Research Assistant) means you get to work closely with one or more post-docs and faculty members in a context that generally requires technical,  problem-solving, and communication skills -- skills that are definitely valued highly by employers.  So, assuming that you do a good job, your supervisors should be able to write strong recommendation letters for you, recommend you to recruiters from industry, or possibly put you in touch with people they know in industry.  Also, you may be able to use your RA work and experience as a discussion item in interviews.

A lot of the industry jobs that undergrads tend to work in look (to me) like grunt-work: website development and maintenance, routine programming, stuff like that.  It seems to me that an RA would be much more preferable than those simply because it can allow you to be more creative and possibly also sharpen your communication skills.  Of course, it's possible that you have some unusual set of skills --- say, Unix guru or security honcho --- that would make you suitable for a very different kind of industry job that would be even more attractive to employers down the road --- but in my experience this tends to be rare.